# Aligning checkbox-group in two columns

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have created checkboxes using checkbox group the checkboxes are in single line I am trying to align in two columns but I have not succeeded.

```html
<lightning-checkbox-group name="Checkbox Group" label="Checkbox Group" options={options} value={value} onchange={handleChange}>
</lightning-checkbox-group>
<p>Selected Values are: {selectedValues}</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I found which does not require rewriting the component is to use the `inline` variant, wrap the `checkbox-group` in `slds-form-element` div, add label with `slds-form-element__label`, and set the style attribute as `columns: 2;`.

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label">
        Multimedia/Artistic skills
    </label>
    <lightning-checkbox-group name="multimediaArtistic" label="Multimedia/Artistic skills"
                              options={multimediaArtisticOptions} value="" variant="label-hidden"
                              onchange={handleChange} style="columns: 4;">
    </lightning-checkbox-group>
</div>
```

[image]

If you would just set the style attribute, the field label would be considered as a member of the column as well, which does not look that good imho.

Answer (score 1):

The [`lightning-checkbox-group`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-checkbox-group/specification) doesn't have a multi-column (or horizontally flowing) variant and there are also [no styling hooks available to modify that aspect of the component](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/checkbox/#Examples) nor [examples of a two column checkbox group in the SLDS library](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/checkbox/#Examples).

All that considered, I think you are left with creating your own component. The below example uses SLDS styling and should get you started:

```html
<div class="slds-form-element">
    <fieldset aria-required="false">
        <legend class="slds-form-element__legend slds-form-element__label">
            Checkbox Group
        </legend>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <div class="slds-grid">
                <div class="slds-col">
                    <span class="slds-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Checkbox Group" id="checkbox-1-1" value="option1" />
                        <label for="checkbox-1-1" class="slds-checkbox__label">
                            <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span>
                            <span class="slds-form-element__label">Jerry</span>
                        </label> 
                    </span>
                    <span class="slds-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Checkbox Group" id="checkbox-1-2" value="option2" />
                        <label for="checkbox-1-2" class="slds-checkbox__label">
                            <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span>
                            <span class="slds-form-element__label">George</span>
                        </label>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col">
                    <span class="slds-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Checkbox Group" id="checkbox-2-1" value="option3" />
                        <label for="checkbox-2-1" class="slds-checkbox__label">
                            <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span>
                            <span class="slds-form-element__label">Elaine</span>
                        </label>
                    </span>
                    <span class="slds-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Checkbox Group" id="checkbox-2-2" value="option4" />
                        <label for="checkbox-2-2" class="slds-checkbox__label">
                            <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span>
                            <span class="slds-form-element__label">Cosmo</span>
                        </label>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this answer, `lightning-checkbox-group` doesn't support columns. You'll need to create your own custom component if you want this feature.